# What would be the correct term for the recipient who's, "in care of" something for someone else

Tags: synonyms

This is usually seen when a letter is sent to someone but the abbreviation, *c/o* is used to indicate that it should be, *in care of* someone else. Just need a more formal term for a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, when you say ***care of***, you are actually saying *at the address of*—and it doesn't need to be a person.

> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/care%20of)
> : at the address of
> // You can write to him *care of* his fan club.
>
> [[Oxford Dictionaries]](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/care_of)
> At the address of.
> ‘write to me care of Ann’
> ‘If you are having similar problems do write to me care of Scotland on Sunday.’

---

But if you're asking about a person to whom correspondence is specifically addressed, there are a few terms I can think of (in addition to just ***intermediary***). These all come from Merriam-Webster. As you'll see, one word leads to another.

[Contact:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contact)

> **3** : a person serving as a go-between, messenger, connection, or source of special information business contacts

[Go-Between:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-between)

> : an intermediate agent : BROKER

[Agent:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agent)

> **4** : one who is authorized to act for or in the place of another

In a business sense, of course, this could just be [**secretary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secretary):

> **1** : one employed to handle correspondence and manage routine and detail work for a superior